Is there a way to conditionally hide field in the pivot table in Quicksight dependent on the user viewing the dashboard?
So what I'm trying to achieve is basically giving access to individual data only to their direct managers, and all other folks can see aggregated data. And in this specific case I want to have manager, login and other different attributes in groupping section and then bunch of metrics calculated based on groups. And then based on the user viewing the dashboard I won't the login filed to be dynamically hided or revealed.
I tried RLS and CLS, but not really working in my use case.
